# Replace all occurences of custom tag with URL in it [JS]

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making an online text editor for a website I'm building, and I use custom tags for the markup.
To make it easier to read, the markup is highlighted by blue, which I do buy using the following function:

```
   var imgOccurences = (informationText.match(/\[img/gi)).length;

   for(var i = 0; i < imgOccurences; i++){
      var imgLocation = informationText.indexOf('[img');
      var endImgLocation = informationText.indexOf(']', imgLocation+1);

      if(imgLocation != -1 && endImgLocation != -1){
         var informationTextTemp1 = informationText.slice(0, imgLocation);
         var informationTextTemp2 = informationText.slice(endImgLocation+1, -1);
         var informationTextTemp3 = informationText.slice(imgLocation, endImgLocation+1);

         informationTextTemp3 = "<span class='highlightWord'>"+informationTextTemp3+"</span>";
         informationText = informationTextTemp1 + informationTextTemp3 + informationTextTemp2;
      }
   }
```

However the problem I face is that, when normalizing the text to HTML, I cannot use **regex** expressions, which I was previously using with the other tags, on the [img] tag, due to the fact that I wanted to highlight the image tag, and all of its contents, which includes a URL.

So I decided to count up all the occurrences of just the '[img' part of the [img] tag and then look for the next occurrence of ']', then slice it out of the normal text, then highlight it using a span, and then add it back to the normal text, while I put it in a for loop. 
However only the first occurrence of the [img] tag is highlighted, and I am unsure as to how I should deal with this. Any help would be appreciated.

**Basically I need to get everything which looks like:** `[img src='www.example.com/image.png']`**and make it look like:**`<span class='highlightWord'>[img src='example.com/image.png']</span>` **and then put it into the `.innerHTML` of the div called `textHighlights`.**

---

Expected result:
[image: 1]

The result I got:
[image: 2]]

Comment: Please provide the relevant HTML and CSS to show a working example of what you have so far.

Comment: And scale this down to just the problem...we don't need to see all the parsing that works as per [mcve] Also provide sample input and expected results

Comment: why re-invent the wheel?  highlight.js

Comment: What about using [mark.js](https://markjs.io)?

Comment: To answer the comments of mike510a and @dude, I just wanted to make it myself :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it much simpler since the `.replace` method accepts a regular expression as a parameter for the matching string.

```
informationText = informationText.replace(/(\[img.+?\])/gi, '<span class="highlightWord">$1</span>');
```

The above will replace all matches directly (*by wrapping them in the `span` you want*)